OpenSSL Accepting Non-Blocking Client connections from the Server
I am quite a new at using openssl, and i'm attempting to accept a nonblocking connection from a blocking server, i've read a couple questions asking exactly this question found here: Non-blocking connect OpenSSL SSL CONNECT produces -1 ERROR
most of the answers say to recall the SSL_accept() function again, how would I go about doing this? would I just do a while (true) loop until the client calls the connection?
here's the current code for accepting the connection
int code = SSL_accept(ssl);
if (code <= 0)
{
    int ssl_error = SSL_get_error(ssl, code);
    if (ssl_error == SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ || ssl_error == SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE)
    {
        //ignore
    }
    else if (ssl_error == SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN)
    {
        //remove connection
    }
    else
    {
        cout << code << endl; //returns -1
        cout << ssl_error << endl; //returns 1 (SSL_ERROR_SSL)
        //remove connection (the code usually leads to here)
    }
}


In short: follow the documentation. It specifically says: "... nonblocking, SSL_accept() will also return when the underlying BIO could not satisfy the needs... The calling process then must repeat the call after taking appropriate action to satisfy the needs of SSL_accept(). ... When using a nonblocking socket, nothing is to be done, but select() can be used to check for the required condition. "

@SteffenUllrich how can I use select to wait for the client to be ready to do the ssl connection?

"how can I use select to wait for the client to be ready to do the ssl connection?" - if you a) understand what select does and how it works and b) understand what SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ means, then you should be able to put these two things together. It is unclear for me what exactly you don't understand here.

@SteffenUllrich I don't understand select in general, since the documentation you have linked me doesn't cover it at all (i'm aware of the fact that it is not a function inside of openssl, which makes sense why it is not being shown as an example on how it can be used)

"I don't understand select in general" - there is plenty of information about this available online - https://www.google.com/search?q=example+select+non-blocking+socket

@SteffenUllrich thanks, what should I do if SSL_ERROR_SSL is called?

Please consult the documentation, which clearly says: "SSL_ERROR_SSL -
A  non-recoverable,  fatal error in the SSL library occurred, usually a protocol error." . So you obviously cannot continue with the handshake but must consider it failed.

@SteffenUllrich alright, this answers all my questions (thanks for your help)
